# can I change the URL in a browser previously opened via my application

Tags: android, url, browser

I have a code in my application to open a browser.
Sometimes I need to tell the browser to load another URL after a few seconds.
Is there a way to make the first browser to change the URL or I need to open a new one always?

Thanks,
  Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would probably be to embed a `WebView` in your application, and then you can control it directly.  Otherwise, as far as I know, you can't control a browser opened up via Intents.  I could be wrong about that, but embedding a `WebView` and controlling it directly seems much more straightforward.

The `WebView` class reference:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Some notes on the `WebView` (less pertinent to what you're doing [this article pertains to writing HTML/native hybrid apps], but may have some useful information):

- http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html